# Concatenation of two languages in NP

Tags: concatenation, np

I have a hard time to understand why the concatenation of two languages over an alphabet, which is in NP, doesn't imply that each of the languages for themselves are in NP. I talked with my Prof about the problem today, but I can't wrap my head around it. Can you help me out?

Comment: Belongs on Computer Science Stack Exchange

Comment: ok, i'm new to this whole network, i ask it there, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a counterexample to the claim that if A and B are languages and AB ∈ **NP**, then A ∈ **NP** and B ∈ **NP**. First, consider all subsets of the set 1*. There are countably infinitely many strings in 1*, so there are *uncountably* many subsets of 1*. Since there are only countably many decidable languages, at least one of these languages is undecidable; let's have that language be A. For B, choose 1*.

My claim is that AB is some language of the form { 1<sup>n</sup> | n ≥ k } for some natural number k. To see this, let k be the length of the shortest string in A. Then any string in AB has the form 1<sup>k+m</sup>1<sup>r</sup>, where 1<sup>k+m</sup> ∈ A and 1<sup>r</sup> ∈ B. Such a string necessarily belongs to { 1<sup>n</sup> | n ≥ k }. Similarly, if we take any string from { 1<sup>n</sup> | n ≥ k }, we can see that it has the form 1<sup>k+m</sup> = 1<sup>k</sup>1<sup>m</sup>, where 1<sup>k</sup> ∈ A and 1<sup>m</sup> ∈ B. Therefore, AB = { 1<sup>n</sup> | n ≥ k }.

The language AB is regular because it's given by the regular expression 1<sup>k</sup>1*, but A is not in **NP** because it's undecidable and all languages in **NP** are decidable.

Hope this helps!